Evaluate an Xpath in OIC with conditions
I want to evaluate an Xpath expression in OIC.
Below is the payload (its actually huge, this is just a shorter version of it):
<executeResponse xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/Invoke_UDSA_TRIM_Data_REQUEST/types">
   <results exportTime="2024-04-30 01:41:02 CDT" dateColumn="report_date" value="6/5/2023" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/nxsd/surrogate/response/Invoke_UDSA_TRIM_Data/">
   <report label="National Daily Pork Report - Negotiated Sales" slug="LM_PK602">
      <record report_date="06/05/2023" is_correction="null" narrative="null">
         <report label="Trim Cuts">
            <record Item_Description="42% Trim Combo" total_pounds="9,120" price_range_low="75.00" price_range_high="90.00" weighted_average="86.91"/>
            <record Item_Description="42% Trim Boxed, FZN" total_pounds="null" price_range_low="null" price_range_high="null" weighted_average="null"/>
            <record Item_Description="72% Trim Combo" total_pounds="122,761" price_range_low="65.00" price_range_high="90.57" weighted_average="73.67"/>
         </report>
         <report label="Variety Cuts">
            <record Item_Description="Breast Bones Poly" total_pounds="null" price_range_low="null" price_range_high="null" weighted_average="null"/>
         </report>
         <report label="Added Ingredients Cuts">
            <record Item_Description="AI Trmd Sparerib - MED, 1 PC VAC" total_pounds="null" price_range_low="null" price_range_high="null" weighted_average="null"/>
         </report>
      </record>
   </report>
</results>
</executeResponse>

This is the condition I need to exaluate to fetch the value of weighted average:
*results\report\record\report[label="Trim Cuts"]\record[Item_Description="42% Trim Combo"] attribute weighted_average*

This is the Xpath I am using:
$Invoke_UDSA_TRIM_Data/nsmpr0:executeResponse/ns17:results/ns17:report/ns17:record/ns17:report[@label='Trim Cuts']/ns17:record[@item_Description='42% Trim Boxed']/@weighted_average

Output is null:
<XxbefPoUsdaltrmStagCollection xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:nstrgmpr="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/database/EBS_DB_DEVA_REQUEST/types" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/database/EBS_DB_DEVA_REQUEST/types">
        <nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStag/>
  </XxbefPoUsdaltrmStagCollection>


Now, I made some changes to the mapping and I am able to fetch the output. But after using for_loop, it seems to be populating all wrong data multiple times.
    xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
    xmlns:nstrgmpr="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/database/EBS_DB_DEVA_REQUEST/types">
</nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStag>
    <nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStag>
        <nstrgmpr:poUsdaltrmStagId>1000</nstrgmpr:poUsdaltrmStagId>
        <nstrgmpr:executionId>1001</nstrgmpr:executionId>
        <nstrgmpr:priceDate>2023-06-05</nstrgmpr:priceDate>
        <nstrgmpr:price42S/>
        <nstrgmpr:price72S/>
        <nstrgmpr:priceTraceLean/>
    </nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStag>
    <nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStag>
        <nstrgmpr:poUsdaltrmStagId>1000</nstrgmpr:poUsdaltrmStagId>
        <nstrgmpr:executionId>1001</nstrgmpr:executionId>
        <nstrgmpr:priceDate>2023-06-05</nstrgmpr:priceDate>
        <nstrgmpr:price42S/>
        <nstrgmpr:price72S/>
        <nstrgmpr:priceTraceLean/>
    </nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStag>
    <nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStag>
        <nstrgmpr:poUsdaltrmStagId>1000</nstrgmpr:poUsdaltrmStagId>
        <nstrgmpr:executionId>1001</nstrgmpr:executionId>
        <nstrgmpr:priceDate>2023-06-05</nstrgmpr:priceDate>
        <nstrgmpr:price42S>94.40</nstrgmpr:price42S>
        <nstrgmpr:price72S>94.40</nstrgmpr:price72S>
        <nstrgmpr:priceTraceLean>94.40</nstrgmpr:priceTraceLean>
    </nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStag>
    <nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStag>
        <nstrgmpr:poUsdaltrmStagId>1000</nstrgmpr:poUsdaltrmStagId>
        <nstrgmpr:executionId>1001</nstrgmpr:executionId>
        <nstrgmpr:priceDate>2023-06-05</nstrgmpr:priceDate>
        <nstrgmpr:price42S>null</nstrgmpr:price42S>
        <nstrgmpr:price72S>null</nstrgmpr:price72S>
        <nstrgmpr:priceTraceLean>null</nstrgmpr:priceTraceLean>
    </nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStag>
    <nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStag>
        <nstrgmpr:poUsdaltrmStagId>1000</nstrgmpr:poUsdaltrmStagId>
        <nstrgmpr:executionId>1001</nstrgmpr:executionId>
        <nstrgmpr:priceDate>2023-06-05</nstrgmpr:priceDate>
        <nstrgmpr:price42S>null</nstrgmpr:price42S>
        <nstrgmpr:price72S>null</nstrgmpr:price72S>
        <nstrgmpr:priceTraceLean>null</nstrgmpr:priceTraceLean>
    </nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStag>
    <nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStag>
        <nstrgmpr:poUsdaltrmStagId>1000</nstrgmpr:poUsdaltrmStagId>
        <nstrgmpr:executionId>1001</nstrgmpr:executionId>
        <nstrgmpr:priceDate>2023-06-05</nstrgmpr:priceDate>
        <nstrgmpr:price42S>104.11</nstrgmpr:price42S>
        <nstrgmpr:price72S>104.11</nstrgmpr:price72S>
        <nstrgmpr:priceTraceLean>104.11</nstrgmpr:priceTraceLean>
    </nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStag>
    <nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStag>
        <nstrgmpr:poUsdaltrmStagId>1000</nstrgmpr:poUsdaltrmStagId>
        <nstrgmpr:executionId>1001</nstrgmpr:executionId>
        <nstrgmpr:priceDate>2023-06-05</nstrgmpr:priceDate>
        <nstrgmpr:price42S>null</nstrgmpr:price42S>
        <nstrgmpr:price72S>null</nstrgmpr:price72S>
        <nstrgmpr:priceTraceLean>null</nstrgmpr:priceTraceLean>
    </nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStag>
    <nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStag>
        <nstrgmpr:poUsdaltrmStagId>1000</nstrgmpr:poUsdaltrmStagId>
        <nstrgmpr:executionId>1001</nstrgmpr:executionId>
        <nstrgmpr:priceDate>2023-06-05</nstrgmpr:priceDate>
        <nstrgmpr:price42S>null</nstrgmpr:price42S>
        <nstrgmpr:price72S>null</nstrgmpr:price72S>
        <nstrgmpr:priceTraceLean>null</nstrgmpr:priceTraceLean>
    </nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStag>
    <nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStag>
        <nstrgmpr:poUsdaltrmStagId>1000</nstrgmpr:poUsdaltrmStagId>
        <nstrgmpr:executionId>1001</nstrgmpr:executionId>
        <nstrgmpr:priceDate>2023-06-05</nstrgmpr:priceDate>
        <nstrgmpr:price42S>null</nstrgmpr:price42S>
        <nstrgmpr:price72S>null</nstrgmpr:price72S>
        <nstrgmpr:priceTraceLean>null</nstrgmpr:priceTraceLean>
    </nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStag>
    <nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStag>
        <nstrgmpr:poUsdaltrmStagId>1000</nstrgmpr:poUsdaltrmStagId>
        <nstrgmpr:executionId>1001</nstrgmpr:executionId>
        <nstrgmpr:priceDate>2023-06-05</nstrgmpr:priceDate>
        <nstrgmpr:price42S>148.19</nstrgmpr:price42S>
        <nstrgmpr:price72S>148.19</nstrgmpr:price72S>
        <nstrgmpr:priceTraceLean>148.19</nstrgmpr:priceTraceLean>
    </nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStag>
</nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStagCollection>

----------This is change in XSLT mapper:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/CUbpSD5r.png

------------This is the xslt code:
```        <xsl:template match="/" xml:id="id_11">
              <nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStagCollection xml:id="id_12">
                    <xsl:for-each xml:id="id_94" select="$Invoke_UDSA_TRIM_Data/nsmpr0:executeResponse/ns17:results/ns17:report/ns17:record/ns17:report/ns17:record">
                          <nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStag xml:id="id_66">
                                <nstrgmpr:poUsdaltrmStagId xml:id="id_67">
                                      <xsl:value-of xml:id="id_68" select="1000"/>
                                </nstrgmpr:poUsdaltrmStagId>
                                <nstrgmpr:executionId xml:id="id_69">
                                      <xsl:value-of xml:id="id_70" select="1001"/>
                                </nstrgmpr:executionId>
                                <nstrgmpr:priceDate xml:id="id_71">
                                      <xsl:value-of xml:id="id_72" select="concat (substring ($Invoke_UDSA_TRIM_Data/nsmpr0:executeResponse/ns17:results/ns17:report/ns17:record/@report_date,7,4),&quot;-&quot;,substring ($Invoke_UDSA_TRIM_Data/nsmpr0:executeResponse/ns17:results/ns17:report/ns17:record/@report_date,1,2),&quot;-&quot;,substring ($Invoke_UDSA_TRIM_Data/nsmpr0:executeResponse/ns17:results/ns17:report/ns17:record/@report_date,4,2))"/>
                                </nstrgmpr:priceDate>
                                <xsl:choose xml:id="id_112">
                                      <xsl:when xml:id="id_113" test="(($Invoke_UDSA_TRIM_Data/nsmpr0:executeResponse/ns17:results/ns17:report/ns17:record/ns17:report/@label = &quot;Trim Cuts&quot;) and ($Invoke_UDSA_TRIM_Data/nsmpr0:executeResponse/ns17:results/ns17:report/ns17:record/ns17:report/ns17:record/@Item_Description = &quot;42% Trim Combo&quot;))">
                                            <nstrgmpr:price42S xml:id="id_114">
                                                  <xsl:value-of xml:id="id_119" select="@weighted_average"/>
                                            </nstrgmpr:price42S>
                                      </xsl:when>
                                </xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:choose xml:id="id_116">
                                      <xsl:when xml:id="id_117" test="(($Invoke_UDSA_TRIM_Data/nsmpr0:executeResponse/ns17:results/ns17:report/ns17:record/ns17:report/@label = &quot;Trim Cuts&quot;) and ($Invoke_UDSA_TRIM_Data/nsmpr0:executeResponse/ns17:results/ns17:report/ns17:record/ns17:report/ns17:record/@Item_Description = &quot;72% Trim Combo&quot;))">
                                            <nstrgmpr:price72S xml:id="id_118">
                                                  <xsl:value-of xml:id="id_120" select="@weighted_average"/>
                                            </nstrgmpr:price72S>
                                      </xsl:when>
                                </xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:choose xml:id="id_122">
                                      <xsl:when xml:id="id_123" test="(($Invoke_UDSA_TRIM_Data/nsmpr0:executeResponse/ns17:results/ns17:report/ns17:record/ns17:report/@label = &quot;Trim Cuts&quot;) and ($Invoke_UDSA_TRIM_Data/nsmpr0:executeResponse/ns17:results/ns17:report/ns17:record/ns17:report/ns17:record/@Item_Description = &quot;Trim w/Trace Combo&quot;))">
                                            <nstrgmpr:priceTraceLean xml:id="id_124">
                                                  <xsl:value-of xml:id="id_125" select="@weighted_average"/>
                                            </nstrgmpr:priceTraceLean>
                                      </xsl:when>
                                </xsl:choose>
                          </nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStag>
                    </xsl:for-each>
              </nstrgmpr:XxbefPoUsdaltrmStagCollection>```


Now I want it to populate the output xml with only 1 value. 


maybe a typo, but using your example xml this predicate [@item_Description='42% Trim Boxed'] should be [@Item_Description='42% Trim Boxed, FZN']

You are correct. Its a typo while pasting here.

Could you then edit your question? Since there are two things wrong:
1. the I of @i should be capital letter,
2. the value of the attribute should 42% Trim Boxed, FZN
